# Authenticating model upload to VertexAI job from Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run a custom training job on VertexAI. The goal is to train a model, save the model to cloud storage and then upload it to VertexAI as a VertexAI Model object. When I run the job from local workstation, it runs, but when I run the job from Cloud Scheduler  it fails. Details below.

**Python Code for the job:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import os
import pickle
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import aiplatform

print("FITTING THE MODEL")

# define dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, n_informative=15, n_redundant=5, random_state=3)
# define the model
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1)
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y)


print("SAVING THE MODEL TO CLOUD STORAGE")
if 'AIP_MODEL_DIR' not in os.environ:
    raise KeyError(
        'The `AIP_MODEL_DIR` environment variable has not been' +
        'set. See https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/tutorials/image-recognition-custom/training'
    )

artifact_filename = 'model' + '.pkl'
# Save model artifact to local filesystem (doesn't persist)
local_path = artifact_filename
with open(local_path, 'wb') as model_file:
    pickle.dump(model, model_file)

# Upload model artifact to Cloud Storage
model_directory = os.environ['AIP_MODEL_DIR']
storage_path = os.path.join(model_directory, artifact_filename)
blob = storage.blob.Blob.from_string(storage_path, client=storage.Client())
blob.upload_from_filename(local_path)


print ("UPLOADING MODEL TO VertexAI")

# Upload the model to vertex ai
project="..."
location="..."
display_name="custom_mdoel"
artifact_uri=model_directory
serving_container_image_uri="us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-4:latest"
description="test model"
sync=True

aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location)
model = aiplatform.Model.upload(
    display_name=display_name,
    artifact_uri=artifact_uri,
    serving_container_image_uri=serving_container_image_uri,
    description=description,
    sync=sync,
)
model.wait()

print("DONE")
```

**Running from Local Workstation:**
I set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to the location of the Compute Engine default service account keys I have downloaded on my local workstation. I also set the AIP_MODEL_DIR environment variable to point to a cloud storage bucket. After I run the script, I can see the model.pkl file being created in the cloud storage bucket and the Model object  being created in VertexAI.

**Triggering the training job from Cloud Scheduler:**
This is what I ultimately want to achieve - to run the custom training job periodically from Cloud Scheduler. I have converted the python script above into a docker image and uploaded to google artifact registry. The job specification for the Cloud Scheduler is below, I can provide additional details if required. The service account email in the `oauth_token` is the same whose keys I  use to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable. When I run this, (either from local workstation or directly in a VertexAI notebook), I can see that the Cloud Scheduler job gets created which keeps triggering the custom job. The custom job is able to train the model and save it to the cloud storage. However, it is not able to upload it to VertexAI and I get the error meessages, `status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED` and `{..."grpc_message":"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.","grpc_status":7`}. Cannot figure out  what the authentication issue is because in both cases I am using the same service account.

```
job = {
  "name": f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/jobs/test_job',
  "description": "Test scheduler job",
  "http_target": {
    "uri": f'https://{location}-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/customJobs',
    "http_method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "User-Agent": "Google-Cloud-Scheduler",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": "..." // the custom training job body,
    "oauth_token": {
      "service_account_email": "...",
      "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    }
  },
  "schedule": "* * * * *",
  "time_zone": "Africa/Abidjan"
}
```

Comment: Can you try explicitly defining `credentials` in [`init()`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/2c6e91f50d2550a693a47fc074d00d861263ecc6/google/cloud/aiplatform/initializer.py#L53)? Just to make sure it uses the correct credentials to authenticate the request.

Comment: Will try that. As yet, the way I could make it work was to add the key to the docker image and set the GOOGLE_APLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the key in the image (probably not good practice to have the key inside the image).

Comment: As you mentioned, it is possible to put a key in your code or image, but this is indeed bad practice. The key might leak more easily if people ever start to work in the same environment, or try to reuse the image or code. Perhaps [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/schedule-cloud-scheduler) helps. It basically suggests that in the scheduler you can add a token (and presumably it will be kept in a safe place and used conveniently)